# '/' as alias name creates error

Tags: c#, sql

I am exporting from a database to excel.  While doing so it is exporting the records as such to the excel.

So I am using an alias name to modify the query in c#.net  but it generates an error.

The query is

```
select name as personsname,eventtime as Date/time from mytable
```

Here the `Date/time`  as alias name creates error

Can anybody guide me to get out of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[Date/time]**

```
select name as personsname,eventtime as [Date/time] from mytable
```